# C++ can't get regex_match to work

Tags: c++, regex

In my code i'd like to process stirngs based on enclosing <> brackets. For this i'd like to go though the string and one by one replace the brackets and do something based on whats inside the brackets.

```
string msg = "This is an <red>Example<> message. For <blue>exampleness' sake<>.";
std::regex rexpr("<[a-zA-Z]*>");

// replace the first set of <> with %c, return the non-replaced version, and process it.
while(true){
    std::smatch smatch;
    // cant find any matches...
    std::regex_match(msg, smatch, rexpr);
    string key = smatch[0]; // this is empty from the start.

    if(key.empty()) break; // no more keys, break.

    // replace <...>
    std::regex_replace(msg, rexpr, "%c", std::regex_constants::format_first_only);

    if(key.size() == 2) continue; // closing brackets, nothing to process

    // cut the brackets
    key = key.substr(1, key.size() - 1);

    // process the key.
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: And what happens if you execute this code?

Comment: nothing is replaced. and regex_match cant find any matches.

Comment: That's a lot of mechanism for something that is essentially `msg.find('<')` and `msg.find('>')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis () around the things you want to catch:

```
string msg = "This is an <red>Example<> message. For <blue>exampleness' sake<>.";
std::regex rexpr("(<[a-zA-Z]*>)");

smatch match;
if( regex_search(msg, match, rexpr) ) {
        cout << match[0] << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
<red>
```

Comment: Yeah it works now, also, had to assing the result of regexp_replace to msg, to actually change the message string and dont get an infinite loop.